# "nothing" in boolean algebra

Tags: notation, boolean-algebra

Is there formal notation for saying "there is no x for which P(x)" or is it simply something like $( \neg \exists x) P(x)$?

Comment: There's nothing informal about using words. Words are great.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sorry, I meant formal notation. I will revise my wording.

Comment: I would use parentheses a little differently but you have the basic idea:  $\lnot  (\exists x P(x))$

Comment: $\not \exists x \mid P(x)$

Comment: In boolean algebra, wouldn't this just be  "For all $x$, $P(x)=0$"? (I mean if it were a logic circuit, you'd just take the $P(x)$  signal directly from the OV supply raill . . .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no established symbol analogous to $\forall$ or $\exists$, no.  You can write either $\neg \exists x. P(x)$ or $\forall x. \neg P(x)$.